# jQuery using values from inside each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code I wrote below works, but the variables I named within the each function are not defined after the function completes.

```js
jQuery.each($myObject, function(i, val) {
  ce = $(this).attr('class');
  if (i === 0) {
    step1complete = true;
    if (/incomplete/i.test(ce)) {
      var step1complete = false
    }
    console.log('step1' + step1complete);
  } else if (i === 1) {
    step2complete = true
    if (/incomplete/i.test(ce)) {
      var step2complete = false
    }
    console.log('step2' + step2complete);
  } else if (i === 2) {
    step3complete = true
    if (/incomplete/i.test(ce)) {
      var step3complete = false
    }
    console.log('step3' + step3complete);
  }
});

if (step1complete === true && step2complete == false && step3 == false) {
  console.log('Youre Just Starting Out I see');
} else {
  console.log('You got one step done now theres more!');
}
```

However, its saying the variables I set in the each function are not defined even though I see them in the console during the loop.

Comment: share the entire code.

Comment: @DamienGold If you understand JavaScript, the above code is enough. `:)`

Comment: @Praveen Kumar I do know javascript.

Comment: @DamienGold Oh sorry. But I was able to find the issue with his code, the moment I saw it. That seems to be the full code. What exactly were you expecting to see? `:)` Just curious to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `var` as it will scope it inside the function that is enclosed. Instead, bring them out, just the `var` part.

```js
var step1complete;
var step2complete;
var step3complete;
jQuery.each($myObject, function(i, val) {
  ce = $(this).attr('class');
  if (i === 0) {
    step1complete = true;
    if (/incomplete/i.test(ce)) {
      step1complete = false
    }
    console.log('step1' + step1complete);
  } else if (i === 1) {
    step2complete = true
    if (/incomplete/i.test(ce)) {
      step2complete = false
    }
    console.log('step2' + step2complete);
  } else if (i === 2) {
    step3complete = true
    if (/incomplete/i.test(ce)) {
      step3complete = false
    }
    console.log('step3' + step3complete);
  }
});

if (step1complete === true && step2complete == false && step3 == false) {
  console.log('Youre Just Starting Out I see');
} else {
  console.log('You got one step done now theres more!');
}
```

If you don't want to pollute the global scope, use an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

```js
(function () {
  var step1complete;
  var step2complete;
  var step3complete;
  jQuery.each($myObject, function(i, val) {
    ce = $(this).attr('class');
    if (i === 0) {
      step1complete = true;
      if (/incomplete/i.test(ce)) {
        step1complete = false
      }
      console.log('step1' + step1complete);
    } else if (i === 1) {
      step2complete = true
      if (/incomplete/i.test(ce)) {
        step2complete = false
      }
      console.log('step2' + step2complete);
    } else if (i === 2) {
      step3complete = true
      if (/incomplete/i.test(ce)) {
        step3complete = false
      }
      console.log('step3' + step3complete);
    }
  });

  if (step1complete === true && step2complete == false && step3 == false) {
    console.log('Youre Just Starting Out I see');
  } else {
    console.log('You got one step done now theres more!');
  }
})();
```

**Definition:**

> **IIFE** (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) is a JavaScript function that runs as soon as it is defined. It is a design pattern which is also known as Self-Executing Anonymous Function and contains two major parts. The first is the anonymous function with lexical scope enclosed within the [`Grouping Operator ()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping). This prevents accessing variables within the IIFE idiom as well as polluting the global scope.

Comment: What does use a closure mean? nvm i see now thanks for example!

Comment: @weekapaug I have updated it to [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). Check out the link.

Comment: @weekapaug IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) is a JavaScript function that runs as soon as it is defined. It is a design pattern which is also known as Self-Executing Anonymous Function and contains two major parts. The first is the anonymous function with lexical scope enclosed within the [`Grouping Operator ()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping). This prevents accessing variables within the IIFE idiom as well as polluting the global scope.

Comment: Great links & examples! cant wait to dig in, thanks!

Comment: A quick newbie question on this.  is var mynewvar the same as saying mynewvar=true?  even though its not set to anything specific?

Comment: @weekapaug No. It's not. Both are different. But `var newVar;` and `var newVar = undefined;` are same. `var newVar = true;` and `newVar = true;` are different. Look at the [scoping of a variable](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/).

Comment: Actually with and without the closure the variables within each() are still undefined outside the function.

Comment: @weekapaug Can you show me a full code that has this problem. Will try to go till the root and solve it.

Comment: @weekapaug It's going to be 1:05 am in UK. I am feeling sleepy mate. Can you show the full code here? Will check it out and make sure it works and then sleep. I am waiting...

Comment: Theres nothing left to do but populate the myobject variable with complete or incomplete.  Something with the structure isnt working exactly as this code sits since it populates fine in the loop to the console but then in the following code after the loop I can not access those variables above.

Comment: @weekapaug Oh... Not sure. Can you show a replication of the issue in https://JSBin.com?